# Erro na posição de token do objeto em Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
const teste = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-54 38.2538,-16 75.2608]}}]}

console.log(teste)



SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected "," (10:134)

   8 |
   9 |
> 10 | const teste = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-54 38.2538,-16 75.2608]}}]}
```

Não consigo identificar o erro

Comment: O erro já diz a resposta, basta ver na posição 134 o que lá existe, ou deixa de existir. No caso é exatamente em `[-54 38.2538,-16 75.2608]`, entre o `-54` e o `38.2538`, é preciso de um `,`.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

O erro está no seu array: "coordinates":[-54 38.2538,-16 75.2608]

esse espaço entre o número -54 e o 38.2538, e entre o -16 e o 75.2608. O JavaScript está esperando que você coloque uma vírgula entre eles. Ex:
"coordinates":[-54,38.2538,-16,75.2608]